# Горизонтальное позиционирование внутри React.Fragment

Tags: css, reactjs, позиционирование

У меня есть вот такая компонента:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Item from "../Item/Item";
import styles from './ItemList.module.css';

const ItemList = ({cards}) => {

    return (
        <>
            { cards.map(item =>
                    <div key={item.id} className={styles.container}>
                        <div className={styles.block}>
                            <Item data={item}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
        </>
    );
};

export default ItemList;
```

И css модуль:

```css
.block {
    width: 320px;
    height: 510px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex-basis: 320px;
    min-height: 510px;
}
```

Проблема в том что элементы отображаются вертикально, тогда как задача сделать это горизонтально. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вынеси контейнер до `map`

```js
import React  from 'react';
import Item   from '../Item/Item';
import styles from './ItemList.module.css';

const ItemList = ({cards}) => {

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {cards.map(item =>
        <div key={item.id} className={styles.block}>
          <Item data={item} />
        </div>,
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemList;
```

[код](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-cray-tc3yjt?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: пробовал. Меняет размеры самой карточки, но отображает всё равно вертикально. Тут дело в Fragment и том как массив Item позиционируется относительно его - в таком направлении думаю.

Comment: @no1imwr а да, не смотрел на ваши стили. надо `flex-flow: row;`

Comment: тоже пробовал, первое что пришло в голову. И оно сработало с div. Но с Fragment никак не срастается..

Comment: @no1imwr я не понимаю о чем речь, я добавил ссылку на рабочий пример

Comment: прошу прощения, vscode сглючил. Да, решение сработало! Вы меня спасли!) Спасибо!